# Python | How do I swap two unknown words in an unknown string?

Tags: python, string, replace, swap

I cannot find how to swap two words in a string using **Python**, without using any external/imported functions.

---

What I have is a string that I get from a text document.
For example the string is:

***line** = "Welcome to your personal dashboard, where you can find an introduction to how GitHub works, tools to help you build software, and help merging your first lines of code."*

I find the longest and the shortest words, from a list, that containts all the words from the **line** string, without punctions.

**longest** = "introduction"

**shortest** = "to"

What I need to do is to swap tthe longest and the shortest words together, while keeping the punctions intact.

Tried using replace, but can only get it to replace 1 word with the other, but the second word remains the same.

Don't know what exactly to use or how to.

The string needs to end up from:
"Welcome to your personal dashboard, where you can find an **introduction** to how GitHub works, tools **to** help you build software, and help merging your first lines of code."

When swapped:
"Welcome to your personal dashboard, where you can find an **to** to how GitHub works, tools **introduction** help you build software, and help merging your first lines of code."

---

Tried replacing it with:
newline = newline.replace(shortest, longest)

But it will only replace 1 word as mentioned before.

Comment: Please share what you have tried, then we can help you troubleshoot the issues you might have.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It's good you mentioned you tried `replace`, but could you provide an example of how you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to split the text into each word and find the min/max words by their size. Afterwards, iterate through the split words and check if it's equal to either the min/max word. If it is, then you need to replace it with the proper word.

```
import string #to check for punctuation

line = "Welcome to your personal dashboard, where you can find an introduction to how GitHub works, tools to help you build software, and help merging your first lines of code."

words = line.split() #this includes punctuation attached to words as well

shortest = min(words, key = len) #find the length of the words that is the smallest

longest = max(words, key = len) #opposite of above

for i, word in enumerate(words): #iterate with both the index and word in the list
    if word == shortest:
        if word[-1] in string.punctuation: #check if the punctuation is at the end since we want to keep it
            words[i] = longest + word[-1] #this keeps the punctuation
        else:
            words[i] = longest
    elif word == longest:
        if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
            words[i] = shortest + word[-1]
        else:
            words[i] = shortest

line = ' '.join(words) #make a new line that has the replaced words
```

Comment: Seems to be working, I'll test it a bit before accepting solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework or an assignment (as in performance does not matter) then my advice to you is to replace word 1 with `{word1}` and word 2 with `{word2}` and then do string format. The solution becomes:

```
line = line.replace(longest, "{word1}").replace(shortest, "{word2}")
line = line.format(word1=shortest,word2=longest)
```

Comment: Almost there: It won't quite work when "to" is a substring of a larger word (say _tools_)

Comment: Performance doesn't matter. ^ Also yea it that works, until there's a word containing one of the words.

Comment: @Dom if you're fine with using regex then you can use `r"\b" + word + "r\b"` which means word start/end. Or you can do as the other answer suggested (which is better) and split on spaces (`string.split()`)